# Why multidimensional array keeps return the key "0"?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
$test = array("sumber"=>array("f1","f2"),"ukraina"=>array("f3","f4"),"0"=>array("f5","f6"));

foreach($test as $key => $value){
    if($key=="sumber"){
    $a='';
    for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){
        $a.=$value[$i].", ";
    }
    echo $key." has ".$a."<br/>";
    }
}
```

and I want the result is like this only

> sumber has f1, f2,

but the result is like this

> sumber has f1, f2,
>
> 0 has f5, f6,

please help me how to display the key "sumber" only???
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use triple conditional `===` in the `if($key=="sumber")` condition:

```
$test = array("sumber"=>array("f1","f2"),"ukraina"=>array("f3","f4"),"0"=>array("f5","f6"));

foreach($test as $key => $value){
    if($key==="sumber"){
    $a='';
    for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){
        $a.=$value[$i].", ";
    }
    echo $key." has ".$a."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Otherwise the `if()` condition is also accomplished when `key` is empty/0.

Comment: Thank you so much fedorqui for the solution and explanation. it really helps.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply used this code :

```
$test = array("sumber"=>array("f1","f2"),"ukraina"=>array("f3","f4"),"0"=>array("f5","f6"));

if(array_key_exists("sumber",$test) && !empty($test['sumber'])) {
    echo "sumber has".implode(",",$test['sumber']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the PHP Manual on comparing values:
[http://www.php.net...comparison.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
   <?php
   var_dump(0 == "a"); // 0 == 0 -> true
   var_dump("1" == "01"); // 1 == 1 -> true
   var_dump(0 === "01"); // false <- what you need
   ?>
```

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to that specific element to start with?

```
<?php
    if (!empty($test["sumber"])) {
        foreach ($test["sumber"] as $values) {
            echo "sumber has " . implode(", ", $values) . "<br />";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: if no 'sumber' key exist then what?